# Excel function with ADODB connection string to Access database

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, connection-string, adodb

I've created below Excel function which connects to an access database with ADODB (approx 10k lines).
It generally works but there are two main issues:

1. It is unreliable: often it returns 0 while the result should be different
2. It is definitely slow

Any suggestion on how to improve?

```
Public Function TotaleSQL(Cat As String, SubCat As String, Anno As Integer) As Long
    On Error Resume Next

    Dim cn As Object, rs As Object, output As String, sql As String
    Dim src As String
    Dim Total As Long
    Dim CatLong As String

    src = "Z:\Report.accdb"

    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & src & ";Persist Security Info=False"
        .Open
    End With


    '---Run the SQL SELECT Query---
    CatLong = "'" & Cat & ":" & SubCat & "'"
    sql = "SELECT Report.Withdrawal, Report.Deposit, Report.Category, Report.Date FROM Report WHERE (((Report.Category)=" & CatLong & ") AND ((Year([date]))=" & Anno & "));"

    'sql = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]"
    Set rs = cn.Execute(sql)

    Total = 0

    Do
       Total = Total + Val(rs(1) & "") - Val(rs(0) & "")
       rs.Movenext
    Loop Until rs.EOF

    '---Clean up---
    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

    TotaleSQL = Total
End Function
```

Comment: It is very likely unreliable because there are errors. Note that you must remove `On Error Resume Next` because this line hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. So if you don't see the errors you cannot fix them and if you don't fix them the code does not work as intended. Remove that line and fix your errors instead. • You might benefit from [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling).

Comment: It is probably slow because of your `Do` loop that loops through all records (if there are many it slows down the process a lot). You obviously just subtract two values and sum them up in total. Try to figure out how to do this in SQL so you don't need to loop. It should be possible with one SQL statement to get that total, without having to loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Cat, SubCat or Anno are user inputs it is more secure to use parameters in your query. For example

```vb
Public Function TotaleSQL(Cat As String, SubCat As String, Anno As Integer)

    Const DATABASE = "Z:\Report.accdb"
    Const TABLE_NAME = "Report"

    Const SQL = " SELECT SUM(iif(Deposit is null,0,Deposit) " & _
                "        - iif(Withdrawal is null,0,Withdrawal)) " & _
                " FROM " & TABLE_NAME & _
                " WHERE Category   = ? " & _
                " AND   YEAR(ddate)= ? "

    Dim cn As Object, cmd As Object, rs As Object
    '---Connecting to the Data Source---
    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    With cn
        .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
        .connectionstring = "Data Source=" & DATABASE & ";Persist Security Info=False"
        .Open
    End With

    ' create command
    Set cmd = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cn
        .CommandText = SQL
        .CommandType = 1 'adCmdText
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P1", 200, 1, 50) ' 1=adParamInput 200=adVarChar
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("P2", 3, 1) ' 3=adInteger
    End With

    ' execute with parameters
    With cmd
        .Parameters(0).Value = Cat & ":" & SubCat
        .Parameters(1).Value = Anno
        Set rs = .Execute
    End With

    TotaleSQL = rs(0)

    rs.Close
    cn.Close
    Set cn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set cmd = Nothing

End Function

Sub test()
    Debug.Print TotaleSQL("Cat", "SubCat", 2020)
End Sub
```

Comment: looks fantastic! thanks!
Only I get following error on line "Set rs = .Execute": Microsoft Visual Basic 
Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': 
The text fie specifcaton 'Report Link Specifcatonl' does not exist. 
You cannot import, export, or link using the specifcaton

Comment: I have Office 2016 Pro, on Win 10 Pro 64 bit

Comment: Tried once more and now I get this error, still on line "Set rs = .Execute": Run-time error '-2147217904 (80040e10)': Too few parameters. Expected 3.

Comment: Sure I changed cat,subcat,2020.
Anyways now I was able to solve it! There was a typing error in SQL "ddate" instead of "date".

Comment: It's now reliable and definetely faster! Even though I'm calling it around 50 times from an excel sheet (as an excel function, then not called from within VBA) and is still keeping the pc busy for quite a while. I'll then disable automatic calculation and insert a button for requering

Comment: @Andrew When I created a test database I used ddate for the field name because date is a reserved word. Forgot to change it, doh !