# How to define a path of access database in a folder instead of CurrentDB in excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have to run an access query via excel vba user form. This query basically find the record from the access table and updates the Out Time. The Table name is "Visitors" and the query name is "updateVisitors". Below is the Excel VBA code I have written :-

```
Sub VisitorsUpdateOT()

Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
Dim con As Object

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = dbs.QueryDefs("updateVisitors")

        qdf.Parameters("Recp_Visitors!OutTime").Value = Recp_Visitors.OutTime.Value
        qdf.Parameters("Recp_Visitors!SrNo").Value = Recp_Visitors.SrNo.Value
        qdf.Execute
        qdf.Close

    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

This code runs perfectly when the access database is open. I figured out that it does not works when the DB is open because of "**Set dbs = CurrentDb**". Is there any way that I can run this query even when the DB is closed?

Comment: You have to have an open connection to get data, but it doesn't have to be `currentDb`. To run it from Excel you will need to get that connection a different way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60326389/8422953

Answer (score 1):

From here https://sourcedaddy.com/ms-access/opening-external-database.html

Change

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
```

to

```
Set dbs = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("C:\Temp\db1.accdb", False, False)
```

Comment: Excel does not know what `DBEngine` is.

Comment: It throws error saying MS Access DB cannot open or write to the file "DB Path". It is already opened exclusively by another user.

Comment: Have you got the MS Access file open? If you've been messing with VBA, it's possible it's still open in an orphan process.

Comment: The last parameter `True` means open read only so you can't write to it. I've edited the answer and set the last parameter to False. See if that works.

Comment: Hi Nick, you are right. I changed the code as below
Set dbs = DBEngine(0).OpenDatabase("DB Path", , False, True)
Thanks a ton everyone... :)

Comment: feel free to accept as the correct anser